# What is the different between transaction fee and gas price?

Tags: solidity, transactions, ethereumjs, sepolia

I deployed a smart contract to `sepolia` network https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x8b309fd585d6f0196dddc5754038e06ef9693f4fd852ec27b02c320a1bc725f5

From the dashboard there are two price, `Transaction fee 0.00321046266632646 ETH ($0.00)` and `Gas price 1.102386156 Gwei` . The value of them are very different. The transaction fee is a thousand times more than gas price. I wonder if it is the total cost to deploy the smart contract? Where can I find the gas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gas price is the price for one gas unit. Means, in the above screenshot, every unit of gas consumed in the transaction costed `1.102386156` wei.

Transaction fees is the amount of ether spent in the transaction, which is obviously the product of `gas price` and `gas used`. Means `1.102386156 * gas used = Transaction fees`.

Remember the transaction fees are given in ethers and `1 ether = 10**9 Gwei`.

Here is the calculation for your contract:

First look at the details given in the transaction-

[image]

The gas price = `1.102386156 Gwei`(means 1 unit of gas costs this much of Gwei)

The gas used in this transaction = `2,912,285`.

Then, total amount for this much gas = `1.102386156 * 2,912,285 = 32,10,462.66632646 Gwei`

Now `1 Gwei = 10 ** -9` so `32,10,462.66632646 Gwei = 32,10,462.66632646 * 10 ** -9 = 0.0032104626663265 Ethers`

We can also write :  `32,10,462.66632646 / 10 ** 9 = 0.0032104626663265 Ethers`

Now talking about the price, here is the conversion:

[image]

Remember the gas fees on mainnet are quite high as compared to sepolia, there will be a significant difference between the costs.

Comment: If I use `transaciton fee` / `gas price`, it is equal to 0.003 eth. The current eth price is $3500, that means deploying a smart contract would cost $1.2? Is it how I should calculate the cost?

Comment: I have added more clarification in the answer @JoeyYiZhao